# Wordpress author page link redirets to top page

Tags: wordpress, author

I'm trying to figure out whats wrong with this website's author page link. The author.php is placed on the theme folder correctly.

This is the only code I have to link it:

```
<p class="autor">por <?php get_the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
```

Here is an example of author page link:
https://aoriente.com/news/author/goncaloasm/

And here is a post. The author link is just bellow the tittle:
https://aoriente.com/news/688/

What might be wrong?

Comment: maybe yoast settings https://kb.yoast.com/kb/disable-enable-author-archives/

Comment: bingo! Could you rewrite it as an  answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author page can be enabled/disabled via Yoast SEO plugin.

You should look at Yoast SEO settings to enable it.

https://kb.yoast.com/kb/disable-enable-author-archives/

Answer (score 1):

We have used your plugin where Wordpress author page link redirets to top page

```
plugin- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/
```

Redirect old domain to a new domain

```
Here’s the code that you will need to add to the .htaccess file of the 
old domain.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```